# IIS SSL error "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long"

Tags: iis, ssl, https, certificate

I have created a certificate using the following SSL command:

> makecert -r -pe -n "CN=www.yourserver.com" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036
>   -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12

I assigned it to a web site on IIS, but when I try to hit the url of the web site I receive:
"SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

`(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)`" when using Firefox.

What is causing it and how to fix it?

Comment: It appears to me that running the dependency checker from the azure training kit and installing the IIS Recommended Configuration fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a typical sign that the SSL port on your IIS server is actually serving plain HTTP.

Have you set the SSL port directive in IIS to 443?  Perhaps if you can show your IIS config?

Also this MS support article may help you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069.

**NOTE** - I've voted to migrate this to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) as it's system-admin related as opposed to programming-related.

Comment: I'm agree with you that this question belongs to serverfault. but stackoverflow has much more users and there is more chanse to find answer here!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee You agree the question should be moved but also say it shouldn't be moved?? That makes no sense. The logic to keep it here is also detrimental to keeping the sites clean. I mean, it's "cheaper" if I steal the loaf of bread, but it's not right...

Answer (score 18):

I had this same exact problem.  Beat my head on the wall for a while, restarting IIS, checking all the settings, Googling for possible answers, etc. etc.  Then I did the magical cure-all for every Windows system:  I restarted the system.  Everything worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score 5):

> "This is a typical sign that the SSL port on your IIS server is actually serving plain HTTP."

Exactly. I had to change Skype to not use ports 80 & 443, that did the trick. Based on solution in this thread: [Applying SSL certificate in IIS manager and "The process cannot access the file because it's being used by another process" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642789/applying-ssl-certificate-in-iis-manager-and-the-process-cannot-access-the-file)

Comment: Thanks for this, turns out it was Skype holding on to port 443 for me too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue caused by my firewall configuration: I misconfigured the portforwarding wrong.

I forwarded port 4444 to 80 insteat to 443. Solved the issue and everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, It was working yesterday at the office and today at home it didn't. In my case was caused becuase the wifi network in my home was classified as Public by Windows, so I switched to Private and it started working