# Functions not working on IIS

Tags: php, mysql, iis, azure

I am using this function to redirect to portfolio after user log in...

```
function redirect($destination) 
{

    //handle url
    if (preg_match("/^https?:\/\//", $destination))
    {
        header("Location: " . $destination);
    }

    // handle absolute path
    else if (preg_match("/^\//", $destination))
    {
        $protocol = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) ? "https" : "http";
        $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        header("Location: $protocol://$host$destination");
    }

    // handle relative path
    else
    {
        // adapted from http://www.php.net/header
        $protocol = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) ? "https" : "http";
        $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        $path = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), "/\\");
        header("Location: $protocol://$host$path/$destination");
    }

    // exit immediately since we're redirecting anyway
    exit;
}
```

On using it produces SSL connection error in chrome:
    Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
in firefox
    An error occurred during a connection to localhost:63077.

```
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Please don't tell me the problem...
tell me solutions or alternative
**I am having a windows azure account...
It's not even working there....**
Kind Regards
Vishal

PS:I know it's going to cost a lot of time ....
I really need this for my imagine cup project ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2522413/215042 Did you even enable SSL and/or install a certificate in IIS? Why are you redirecting to 63077 and not 443?

Comment: @Robll It's not working on windows azure too...

Comment: My comment goes for IIS, Azure, Apache, whatever you may be using. In each case you'd need to configure SSL/install certificates etc. And probably using port 63077 doesn't help while troubleshooting this problem too...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are having issues getting the correct protocol. I'm not sure if this will work on IIS, but I generally use the following on Linux - can't imagine why it wouldn't work:

```
function getProtocol()
{
        return $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=='443'?'https://':'http://';
}
```

That should remove most of the complexity in your code?